# UPDATE not updating database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to update the database information, however it's not updating, it does show a successful message once submitted, however it doesn't want to update.

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../_lib/inc/config.php');
session_start();

    if ($_SESSION['username']) {

    }else {

    }
        $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reviews WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($grab);

        $author = $row['author'];
        $comment = $row['comment'];
        $company = $row['company'];
        $id = $row['id'];
?>

<?php 

    if ($_POST) { 
        $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
        $author = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['author']);
        $company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);   
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);     

        if ($author == "") {    
                echo ('<div class="alert alert-error" style="margin: 8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Error:</strong> Please enter something into the author field!</div>');
        }   
        elseif ($company == "") {   
            echo ('<div class="alert alert-error" style="margin: 8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Error:</strong> Please enter something into the company field!</div>');
        }
        elseif($comment == "") {
            echo ('<div class="alert alert-error" style="margin: 8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Error:</strong> Please enter something into the comment field!</div>');  
        } else {

            // Insert the review
            $insertReviews = "UPDATE reviews SET author='$author', company='$company', comment='$comment' WHERE id='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'";
            mysql_query($insertReviews) or die("MySQL Error - Could not insert reviews");

            echo ('<div class="alert alert-success" style="margin: 8px; text-align: center;"><strong>Success:</strong> Your review has been successfully submitted!</div>');        
        } 
    }
        else {  
    }   
?>
```

the form:

```
<form action="reviews/viewReview.php" method="POST" name="#load">

    Review Author:
    <br />
    <input name="author" size="8" type="text" class="userpass" value="<?php echo $author ?>"/>
    <br /><br />

        <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>"/>

    Company Name:
    <br />
    <input name="company" size="8" type="text" class="userpass" value="<?php echo $company ?>"/>
    <br /><br />

    Review Comment:
    <br />
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="6" cols="35"><?php echo $comment ?></textarea>
    <br /><br />

    <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Update Article" />

</form>
```

any ideas why it's not updating the information set in the database?

Comment: your code is indicating that you're not getting `$_GET`, because you are using `$_GET['id']` in `if($_POST){` .. to get $_GET in form submission you have to mention in it in `<form action="reviews/viewReview.php?id=2"`

Comment: Or put hidden input element for `id` and get it as `$_POST['id']`

Comment: And don't use mysql_*function as it's deprecated now.. use mysqli or PDO instead...[See Here](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: @ShaunakShukla so something like `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id ?>"/>` ?

Comment: yes.. As you're updating the row, so you can get it from DB or from $_GET as well for edit form page..

Comment: @ShaunakShukla apologies, but i'm still not getting it. i've updated the above code, i added the ID, but somehow it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have to change `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])` to `mysql_real_escape_string($id)` to be worked!!

Comment: your using method $_POST on your form while you use $_GET on the query.. you wont really get to update it if its like that .. if you use $_GET on your form then use $_GET or $_POST in your form then use $_POST on your backend

Answer (score -1):

Instead of
        "mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])"
simply use
         "mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id'])"

Comment: id is the hidden field here, I am well aware of sql injection, in this scenario he just need to simplify to check whether it worked or not

Comment: The fact it's a hidden field does not mean anything in this matter. Everything that comes from client-side can be falsified and must be verified.